# Python module Pisa: how change background color for all page?

Tags: pdf, python-2.7, background, pisa

How i can change background color of all page?

like this :

`body,div { background-color:#f4f4f4; }`

Now background changes only for div with information,  remaining page have white color. if it is possible, can you write example?

P.s. How i can draw border around  ?

Answer (score 2):

Acording to the documentacion https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/usage.rst#supported-page-properties-and-values @page only accept few css propierties:

background-image
size
margin, margin-bottom, margin-left, margin-right, margin-top

So maybe the easyest is to make a jpg to draw the background with background color and border. And use that image in  background-image propierty:

```
@page {background-image: url('local_path/to/your/image.jpg')}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you

```
html,body{height:100%}
body,div { background-color:#f4f4f4; }
```

and your Second Question > How i can draw border around ?

add

```
border:1px #ccc solid
```

Comment: no, its don t work ( if i use html,body{height:100%} : WARNING [xhtml2pdf] /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xhtml2pdf/util.py line 257: getSize: Not a float '100%'
if i use  html,body{height:3600} not a full page have background (

Comment: and " P.s. How i can draw border around ? " - i don t write full phrase. i mean " P.s. How i can draw border around img tag ? "

Comment: About border around: <div style="display: block; background-color: #e6e6e6; border: 1px solid #646464;"><img style="width: 350px; height: 262.5px; display: block;" src="{{ imageData }}"/></div>

Comment: I think you cannot apply background-color to body. Just use background-image to @page like in answer bellow.