# Pisa html2pdf background-image not working

Tags: django, pdf, background-image, background-color, pisa

Im trying to set a background color in pdf generated with pisa. I have seen this post [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348998/python-module-pisa-how-change-background-color-for-all-page) and try to implement them, but the background only display in a part of the pdf. This is my code:

```html
{% load app_filters %}
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Ficha Técnica</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   @page {
    size: {{ pagesize|default:"A4" }};
    margin-left: 2.5cm;
    margin-right: 2.5cm;
    margin-top: 2cm;
    margin-bottom: 2cm;
    background-image: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}pdf/fondo.png');
    

    @frame header {
     -pdf-frame-content: page-header;
     margin-top: 0.7cm;
     margin-right: 2mm;
     margin-bottom: 0cm;
     margin-left: 1.2cm;
    }

    @frame footer {
     -pdf-frame-content: page-footer;
     bottom: 0cm;
     margin-left: 1cm;
     margin-right: 1cm;
     height: 1cm;
    }


   }

  @font-face {
   font-family: "light";
   src: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-light-webfont.ttf');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
  }
  @font-face {
   font-family: "bold";
   src: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}fonts/yanonekaffeesatz-bold-webfont.ttf');
   font-weight: normal;
   font-style: normal;
  }
  .logo{
   margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .general img{
   width: 400px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  .titulo{
   font-family: "bold";
   font-size: 22px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color:#808080;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   letter-spacing: "1";
  }
  .general p{
   font-family: "light";
   font-size: 13px;
   color:#808080;

  }
  .line{
   width:200pt; 
   border-top: 2px solid #808080;
   color:white;
   font-size: 1px;
  }
  .bases
  {
   font-family: "bold";
   font-size: 12px;
   color:#808080;
  }
  .bases table {-pdf-keep-in-frame-mode: shrink;}
  .bases img{
   width:85px;
  }
  table{text-align: center;}
  </style>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="logo">
   <center><img src='{{ STATIC_URL }}pdf/logo_pdf.png'></center>
  </div>
  <div class="general">
   <center><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{Proto.image}}" alt=""></center>
   <h1 class='titulo'>{{Proto.name|upper}}</h1>
   <p>{{Proto.description}}</p>
  </div>
  <div class='line'>.</div>
  <div class="bases">
   <h1 class='titulo'>BASES SELECCIONADAS</h1>
   <center>
    <table>
     <tr>
     {%for detalle in ProtoDetalle%}
     <td>
      <center><img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{detalle.base.especificImage}}" alt=""></center>
      <br>
      <h2>{{detalle.base.name|upper}}</h2>
      <h2>{{detalle.tela.name|upper}}</h2>
      <table>
       <tr>
        <td style='width:100px;'></td>
        <td><h2>{{detalle.color.name|split_by:"-"}}</h2></td>
        <td style='background-color:{{detalle.color.color}}; color:{{detalle.color.color}}; width:50px; font-size: 5px; border: 1px solid black;'>.</td>
        <td style='width:100px;'></td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
     {%endfor%}
     </tr>
    </table>
   </center>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The background image is just a color square 36px by 36px.

I tried to set background-color to body,html,div but only divs with content take the color. so i dont understand why the background-image property only sets in a porcent of the pdf displayed.

Any idea what is my mistake?

this is the current result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved making a background image with the same size of A4 page (297 x 210 mm). Now the background cover all the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working with pdf background, which I would suggest.
Note that the (lightweight) documentation mentions only pdf background.
https://xhtml2pdf-base.googlecode.com/hg/doc/xhtml2pdf-en.html